# Why can't the .ico file be inserted into the Userform Image Object in Excel 2013 VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, office-2013, .ico

Office 2013 64-bits, Windows 7:
I tried to insert a picture (file .ico) but couldn't. I do not understand why.
But with an other PC (Office 2016 64-bits, Windows 10), it is OK.

Please explain to me the reason and how to fix it.

Comment: Please add the relevant code you tried so far to load the icon to your Userform's Image control and describe the module where you launch it. Which error message do you get, *"I tried to ..., but couldn't"* doesn't help to detect the possible cause. You are invited to have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), where MCVE stands for a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample allowing to reproduce the issue :-)

Comment: Error: https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2020/05/30/Captureebd1bc4a76305c1c.png File demo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sAuwniOPYFUEt5ITPCvveWlRc9fwlL6T/view

Comment: It's good use to *edit* the necessary code in your post to be in the position to facilitate reading and to reproduce the issue, not to send an image or link.